# Error after upgrading to latest version of Visual Studio 2022 and project is not being loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have upgraded Visual Studio 2022 from 17.1.4 to 17.1.5.

When I open the solution, the main project (ASP.NET Core) remains unloaded. When I try to load the project I get the following error:

> The expression "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(C:\pathtoproject, \net6.0)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path.  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First thing I'd try is to run the Repair from the Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Other projects work fine. One this project doesn't.

Comment: And you are sure that "pathtoproject" does not contain any illegal characters?

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete all files in "/Bin" and "/Оbj" folders across Solution. Also do a "Clean solution" before build.

Answer (score 0):

Download .NET SDK (6.0) and make repair. After restart your PC

[.NET SDK LINK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Solution, there you will find an option for "Load All Projects", click on that option and it will load all the projects, you can also unload the project by clicking on "Unload the projects"